# Is there a way to limit the amount of records my mapreduce(JAVA) job produces?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Lets say I want to produce only 1000 records from my mapreduce program.
I have multiple mappers going into one reducer, so limiting the number of records coming from mapper isn't an option.

Does mapreduce have some built in function where I can do something like

```
HCatOutputFormat.setOutput(job, OutputJobInfo.create(dbName, tbName, partitionValues)).limit(1000);
```

or something similar like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use inbuilt MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS counter for that.
[Here](http://lintool.github.io/Cloud9/docs/content/counters.html) is the example